# Las etiquetas HTML script y style se "incrustran" en la web como elementos inline a pesar de haberlos definido desde el atributo src

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

a ver si me explico bien.

Tengo el problema que las etiquetas HTML script y style se "incrustran" en la web como elementos inline a pesar de haberlos definido desde el atributo src. Lo extraño del caso es que esto me sucede solo cuando me conecto desde fuera de la red de mi trabajo, cuando entro desde la red de mi trabajo el código funciona bien. Uso el Framework Codeigniter de PHP

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('css/' . $this->config->item('theme') . '/jquery-ui.css')?>" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url('js/general/jquery.util.js')?>"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     Hola mundo
  </body>
</html>
```

El resultado cuando sucede el problema es el siguiente (inspeccionando el código fuente desde el navegador, fuera de la red de la empresa):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
     <style style="display:none">.......código css inline......</style>
     <script type="text/javascript" style="display:none">.......código js inline......</script>
  </head>
  <body>
     Hola mundo
  </body>
</html>
```

Y cuando se ejecuta bien es el siguiente (dentro de la red de la empresa):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="ruta-hacia-el-fichero">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="ruta-hacia-el-fichero"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     Hola mundo
  </body>
</html>
```

Mi problema con esto es porque luego con JS uso el atributo SRC de una etiqueta script para hacer x cosas y cuando da el error pues el atributo SRC no existe porque se ha incrustado como un elemento inline en la web.

Espero haberme explicado bien,

Gracias por cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no se me ocurre porque el error , lo único que se me imagina revisar es la configuración de ambos webservers (tanto en el lugar de tu empresa , y en el lugar fuera de tu empresa) , php.ini de ambos web servers. ESO si te refieres a 2 maquinas diferente al decir fuera y dentro de la red de mi empresa ,

pero si no te refieres a eso y te refieres a que simplemente estas con la ip de tu empresa y luego sin la ip de tu empresa , ahí te recomiendo que verifiques las rutas del SRC que se están generando y del base_url que tienes configurado, para que veas que si este apuntado bien independiente de que red estés conectado.

Espero encuentres la solución :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usar base_url() concatenando la ruta de los archivos en vez de enviar la ruta como parámetro a la función:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url() . 'css/' . $this->config->item('theme') . '/jquery-ui.css'?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url() . 'js/general/jquery.util.js'?>"></script>
```